# Rails custom select with partial for collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a Stay which `has_many_and_belongs_to :rooms`. Rooms are created by admin so they aren't created along with Stays therefore I'd like to be able to select rooms from given collection but I'd like to create custom looking select in my case using `simple_fields_for`.

The code I have in my form partial in order to achieve what I want:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :rooms, Room.available  do |rf|
 = render 'reservations/form/resource', f: rf
```

My resource partial so far has only one line: `= f.hidden_field :id, value: f.object.id`

And when I hit refresh I get:

```
undefined method `id' for #<Room::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007feb6f3fc2f0>
Did you mean?  ids
```

but when I try ids I only get one hidden input which has this code:
`<input value="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" type="hidden" name="reservation_stay[rooms][id]" id="reservation_stay_rooms_id">`

How do I make it create an input for every room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common misconception is that `fields_for` (or the SimpleForm wrapped `simple_fields_for`) should be used when assigning associations (linking records together) - it is only relevant if you are using `accepts_nested_attributes` to create or update nested resources in the same form.

When assigning associations from a collection in Rails you pass a `_ids` (`rooms_ids`) param with an array.

For example:

```
Stay.first.update(room_ids: [1, 2, 3])
```

The `_ids` setter automatically creates or removes the associations - even if they are indirect.

Thats how the [form options helpers in Rails work](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.htmlr).

```
<%= f.collection_select :rooms_ids, Room.available, :id, :room_number %>
```

The easiest way to get the correct params with a custom UI is to actually use a select and hide it instead of using a hidden input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer now I get it but I've got related question. What about if I want to change the Room status when it's linked with Stay?

Comment: You need to rethink how you have modeled this. If you where to change the status on the rooms table when a reservation is created it would essentially lock the room even if the reservation is a month ahead. Instead you want to use `has_many :through` and store the dates of a reservation in the join table. I would set it up as Booking has_many Reservations. Reservation belongs to Room. but this is really a seperate question.

Comment: There are probally plenty of examples of a rails booking application if you search around a bit.